# Do you need to submit the original US passport while renewing OCI in India?

Tags: us-citizens, indian-citizens

If you are renewing OCI card for minor in India, do you need to submit the original US passport? If yes, do we need to submit both old and new US passports?

Comment: What research have you done so far to try to find out?